# Email rendering issue with native email application on Iphone

Tags: html-email

One month ago, I integrated a email in HTML for one of my client. The rendering with the native email application on Iphone was perfect. But today, I have a big issue with this email. I don't change any line of code but the final rendering is a desaster.
Some line of codes appears in the rendering in the email and at the end.
Image of the rendering: http://i42.tinypic.com/91f2wj.png

Maybe iPhone have change one rules. Do you have any idea to fix this ?

Thank you so much for helping me!!

My email code is available here:
http://tinyurl.com/p3eqe5d

Edward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is presented by Michelle Klann of Email on Acid:

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/ensure_that_your_entire_email_is_rendered_by_default_in_the_iphone_ipad

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues:

one being that you use relative paths for images (`src="images/image_pull_right_3.jpg"`). It looks fine online, but gmail won't know what to do with a file path relative to the html file once that file is on their servers. That said, I don't know how the rest of your images are loading at all.

another is that you aren't encoding your special characters (â, à, should be `&acirc;` `&agrave;` etc). That can cause issues in a number of clients/browsers.

Hopefully doing both of those things will fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did a big mistake, problems don't come from gmail on iphone but from the native application on iphone. 
For the relative paths, my email marketing solution change automatically to absolute path.
I will try to encode my special characters, maybe that will fix my problems. Thank you so much for your time !!